# What do the single quotes in if [ `wc -c $i` -gt 3 ] mean?

Tags: linux, shell

[image]

`$1` is DirectoryName

`$2` is txt (file extension)

`$3` is 500 (or any other positive integer)

---

I don't understand the syntax of single quotes. I think what its supposed to do is to find all text files in a directory name passed in as parameter one, then do a "character count" of the txt files that come up in the search and if the character count is over a specified amount passed in parameter 3, then change the file permissions.

however it doesn't actually work. it says "expects an integer". Now it could be that the question is trying to trick me. But I can't get it to work either by changing it slightly. I've tried removing the single quotes (error says "too much data or something), using double quotes instead (something about syntax), I tried using a pipe or >. I read somewhere that single quotes was supposed to make everything inside literal, so that a $asdf would be taken as $asdf literal characters, but then the commands wc -c should have also failed, instead I am told it is expectinng a non=existent integer.

I even tried to play around with substituting variables like

a = wc -c $i
echo $a

which failed with token / syntax errors.

---

could someone please help with any concepts here that I've totally misunderstood? I have an exam tomorrow and this is past papers, so it's totally for revision only.

Comment: These are backticks (`\``), not single quotes (`'`). The term to google is "command substitution". Modern code should be using `$(..)` , which does the same thing but cleaner and without the readability problem.

Comment: I hope they're not teaching that as an example of good code -- it's not just the use of antiquated command substitution syntax that's a problem, but also the lack of proper quotes; it *should* be `[ "$(wc -c "$i")" -gt "$3" ]`

Comment: its a past exam paper, so i don't know if it's a trick question. but could you please explain why you added double quotation marks please?

Comment: Quotes are also very important here: `chmod a+r "$i"`.

Comment: @youknownothingjonsnow, if quotes aren't used on an expansion, then it's subject to string-splitting and glob expansion. So if you had a filename that had spaces, for instance, it would be split into two separate arguments if you didn't quote. If the `IFS` variable had numbers in it, moreover, those digits would be removed during the string-splitting process if they were present in output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not single-quotes but rather backticks (`). You might want to search for 'Command Substitution' in bash's man.